# How to set s.source_files path & s.resource_bundles path in .podspec

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, github, cocoapods

I am writing a Cocoapod myself and I am stuck in the .podspec file to set up the path.
I have used many ways to set the path of s.source_files & s.resource_bundles but still, I am getting the same error.

Command

```
    1. pod trunk register -> Successfully 
    2. pod lib lint.      -> Successfully
    3. pod trunk push     -> Error
```

- ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.

I am sharing my file hierarchy please help me to set Path.

## .podspec file code

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'RandomDataGenerator'
  s.version          = '1.0.0'
  s.summary          = 'RandomDataGenerator is very easy to use and very usefull for Lorem Data'



  s.description      = <<-DESC
  'A RandomDataGenerator is a library which is basically used to Generate a number of Random Data for UITAbleView and UICollectionView or for normal bunch of Data. Suppose that if you your app is in Developement Phase and You have not yet implemeted any API for your app but still you want to display Random data in your UI so you can use this to generate Random Data.'
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/kumarlav0/RandomDataGenerator/tree/master'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'kumarlav0' => 'kumarstslav@gmail.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/kumarlav0/RandomDataGenerator.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.social_media_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/kumarstslav/'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '12.0'
  s.source_files = 'RandomDataGenerator'
  s.requires_arc      = true
  s.swift_version = '5.0'
  s.platforms = {
      "ios": "12.0"
  }
  
end
```

.podspec file

[image]

File Hierarchy

[image]

File Hierarchy Closed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`s.source` should point to a tagged version of the repository with that directory structure. See `spec.version` and `spec.source` in the example at https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html

Comment: I tried almost all the ways but still, I am getting the same error. Please tell me the exact path from my project. What should be the path.?

Comment: s.source should be the Git Repo

Comment: still, I m not getting

Comment: Please update the question with the full podspec.

Comment: I updated my question with a full .podspec file please check and help me.

Comment: I don't see any sources at that tag in the referenced GitHub repo. See https://github.com/kumarlav0/RandomDataGenerator/tree/1.0.0

Comment: See:  https://github.com/kumarlav0/RandomDataGenerator/tree/master

Comment: It doesn't matter what's in master. The tag version is what CocoaPods uses. You should move the 1.0.0 tag to master if that's what you want to be picked up.

Comment: Oh ok, I will do that.